# Spring boot actuator: ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC before Application Starts

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

My spring boot app includes Spring Cloud Stream. Before the application boot it takes time for Spring Cloud Stream to connect to broker.

So the current sequence

1. Spring Boot Actuator's ReadinessState changed to  ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2. Wait for Spring Cloud Stream Broker
3. Application Starts.
4. Again a debug log saying that ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC

I don't want to state to be ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC on step 1 because application has not started by then. Am I missing something here?

I have added following application properties, and no other configuration

```
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true
```

Comment: Can you verify if you fall within the scenario of this issue?
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2083